# How to manage screen orientation in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have two view controller in my app.
1st view controller is portrait mode and 2nd view controller in landscape mode.

I don't want to change their orientation even when i rotate my iPhone.
How can i make?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Xcode, highlight the project in the Project Navigator, and select the target in the project tree. Open the Summary page, and go to the Supported Interface Orientations section. Un-click the orientations that you do not want your application to support.

In the story board, choose your first view controller, go to the Attributes inspector, and set orientation to "Portrait" in the Simulated Metrics section. Now choose the second view controller, and set its orientation to "landscape".

In the view controller code, implement

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

for the first view controller, and

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

for the second view controller. This should fix the problem for you.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. I already do that. My app support only portrait, landscape left and right. But, 1st view controller only want to use portrait and 2nd view controller only want to use landscape left and right. How can i manage it?

Comment: @desblinkenlight, millions in thanks. You really help me. It is identity with my need. Thanks you very much. :)

Comment: Beware, this answer is for iOS 6 and later.  If you have your app's "Deployment Target" set below 6.0; be sure to add additional code to cover iOS 5 etc.  Best of luck.

Comment: What would compell anyone to downvote an accepted answer after a "you really helped me" comment? This makes zero sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

In your case you have two VCs. So in both VC under below method just handle you orientations. and perform check against toInterfaceOrientation and return YES.

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
     // For your VC1
     if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
           return YES;
     // For your VC2
     /*
     if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
           return YES;  
     */

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your help also help me in my development. Thanks you.